# How to check "interrupt" information in windows?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, operating-systems

I want to know that is there any way using which we can see the interrupt information or interrupt number or interrupt log in windows or Linux.

Comment: in Windows you can use xperf to trace ISR activity

Answer (score 1):

Windows:
Open Device Manager (Right click My Computer -> Properties -> Device Manager). go to the View menu, and select "View Resources by Type". you will see a node called "Interrupt Request (IRQ)" which will list all your known IRQs.

Ubuntu:

```
sudo cat /proc/interrupts
```

There is no logging of Interrupt events. that would kill your CPU.